# Cursor Adapter for the List view is not showing most recent values

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using a SimpleCrusorAdaptor to display a list of items in a list view. When an item in listview is selected it starts an other activity, this activity changes the puzzle status which is shown in the list view. When this activity terminates and activity containing the list view  again becomes active, list view shows the old status,

How can I ensure if the activity containing list view resumes, the cursor adapter updated the values ? Some thing to be done in onResume() of the cativity ?

```
private static String[] FROM = { PuzzleDatabase.KEY_PUZZLE_TITLE,
PuzzleDatabase.KEY_PUZZLE_STATUS };
private static int[] TO = { R.id.puzzle_title, R.id.puzzle_status };

 ListView  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.puzzle_list);

 this.cursor = ps.puzzleDatabase.getPuzzleTitles();

 // Set up data binding
          SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.puzzle_list_row, cursor, FROM, TO);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the updating values try doing this

```
class YourClass extends Activity{
   //other members
   private Bundle savedInstanceState;   //add this to your code
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;    //add this to your code

    //your other code here 
   }
    @Override
protected void onResume() {                     //add this function to your code
    datasource.open();                      //change datasource to your own database class's object
    super.onResume();
    onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
}

}
```

Comment: onCreate(savedInstanceState);     Its must be called in onRestart()

Answer (score 1):

The cursor doesn't change its contents, just because the underlying dataset changes its contents!  The cursor contains the data that resulted from the query, at the time the query was made.

You need a Loader.  You can see find example code here:

https://github.com/marakana/yamba/blob/yambaII/Yamba/src/com/marakana/android/yamba/TimelineActivity.java

You must, first, initialize the loaderManager.  Next hand it a loader when it calls you back.  Finally, you must swap the loader into the adapter when you it calls you back after the loader has run.

Of course, you have to notify the cursor that it is out of date, too.  There is example code for that, here:

https://github.com/marakana/yamba/blob/yambaII/YambaService/src/com/marakana/android/yamba/svc/data/YambaProvider.java

See, e.g., line 182